# Can i allow specific device to access node.js server and block all the others?

Tags: node.js

I have built an iOS app that uses a node.js server to access a Mongo database through some endpoints. Is it possible to allow specific devices to access these endpoints and block all the other devices?

I'm thinking something like a list of allowed MAC addresses or other unique id because server is running in a LAN.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.  A good solution would be to add some sort of key to your request and you only respond to requests with a valid key.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your solution is good enough but I would prefer a server side solution without altering the request code from client side.